# categorise an element in Array for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm New to JS

I have an Array and An object of the Same Array.

I want to get the Total Number to a specific category.

For E.g :

```
1.Critical: from 30-45
2.High: from 16-27
3.Medium: from 5-15 
4.Low:from 3-4
```

The array Layout I got it in two formats.

From the browser:

```
    slect_score
    [{…}]0:
     4: 1
     5: 3
     15: 6
     20: 1
     30: 2
     45:2
     __proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array(0)
```

From the Browser:

```
    score_map
{4: 1, 5: 3, 15: 6, 20: 1, 30: 2, 45: 2}

__proto__:Object
```

All in All, I want to group the number and get the total number of appearance to each category.

For the Example Above: I should have :

```
            1.Critical: 4
            2.High: 1
            3.Medium: 9
            4.Low: 1
```

Here is my Code: I'm trying to insert it into Django Template:

```
        var score = document.getElementById("score").innerHTML;
        var score_array = [score.split(",").map(Number)];
        var score_array_a = score_array[score_array.length -1];
        var score_array_b = score_array_a.slice(0, -1);
        var score_sum = score_array_b.reduce(function(a, b){ return a +                         
        b;}, 0);
        var score_avg = parseFloat(score_sum / score_array_b.length);




        var score_map = score_array_b.reduce(function(obj, b) {
          obj[b] = ++obj[b] || 1;
          return obj;
        }, {});

        var slect_score = new Array(score_map);
```

In my Django Template:

```
    <p  id=score>
    {% for asset in self.get_children %}{% for finding in        
     asset.get_children.specific %}
    {% with finding.Identification|mul:Reconize                 
    as ID_REC %}{{ID_REC|mul:Impact}},{% endwith %}{% 
    endfor %}{% endfor %}
    </p>
```

The Django Elements is mainly for Calculation and get the number of Each page and it's Calculation

```
THE ANSWER

The Code of Mr. Bergur. And The way I made it to get the total number of each category.
```

```
    var score = document.getElementById("vul_score").innerHTML;
    var score_array = [score.split(",").map(Number)];
    var score_array_a = score_array[score_array.length -1];
    var score_array_b = score_array_a.slice(0, -1);
    var score_sum = score_array_b.reduce(function(a, b){ return a +         
    b;}, 0);
    var score_avg = parseFloat(score_sum / score_array_b.length);



    var score_map = score_array_b.reduce(function(obj, b) {
      obj[b] = ++obj[b] || 1;
      return obj;
    }, {})


    var scoore = Object.entries(score_map).map(e => Object.assign(e, {         
    0: +e[0]                 }));

    const scores = [{
      name: 'critical',
      low: 30,
      high: 45,
      count: 0
    },{
      name: 'high',
      low: 16,
      high: 27,
      count: 0
    },{
      name: 'medium',
      low: 5,
      high: 15,
      count: 0
    },{
      name: 'low',
      low: 3,
      high: 4,
      count: 0
    }]

    const score_map_keys = Object.keys(score_map);

    scores.forEach(s  => {
      score_map_keys.forEach(key => {
        let count = score_map[key];
        if (key >= s.low && key <= s.high) {
          s.count = s.count+count
        }
      });
    })
```

And To get The total Number from Each catagory I did :

```
  [scores[0].count, scores[1].count, scores[2].count, scores[3].count]
```

I really want to thank Mr. Bergur.

Comment: Please, post your code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post the actual JavaScript code defining your objects, rather than text renderings of what the browser console shows you when you dump them out. The actual code is much clearer and makes it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: Separately, even if you're new, your best bet is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: What happens if somebody has 28? High is 27 but critical starts at 30

Comment: The Calculation Can not be 28, It has a fixed Number. for calculation purposes.

Comment: T.J. Crowder, I did research for two hours, couldn't find a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this. Here is one way.

1- You have the scoring system, but you need to arrange it in a way that a code can read through it.

One way would be:

```
const scores = [{
  name: 'critical',
  low: 30,
  high: 45,
  count: 0
},{
  name: 'high',
  low: 16,
  high: 27,
  count: 0
},{
  name: 'medium',
  low: 5,
  high: 15,
  count: 0
},{
  name: 'low',
  low: 3,
  high: 4,
  count: 0
}]
```

Here you have an array of objects. Each object has 4 properties: The name, the highest allowed value, the lowest allowed value and the current count. Which we will be modifying later in the code.

2- We can loop through that array with .forEach

```
scores.forEach(scoreObject => {
  console.log('This is '+ scoreObject.name)
  console.log('Highest value is '+ scoreObject.high)
  console.log('Lowest value is '+ scoreObject.low)
})
```

3- You also have the count for each score but you have to be able to loop through it to add it all up. This is a javascript object and the best way to loop through javascript objects is to use Object.keys.

```
const score_map = {
  4: 1,
  5: 3,
  15: 6,
  20: 1,
  30: 2,
  45: 2
}

const score_map_keys = Object.keys(score_map);
```

4- We can loop through all the score counts.

```
score_map_keys.forEach(key => {
  let count = score_map[key];
  console.log('Key ' + key + ' has value ' + count);
});
```

5- Now we can put it all together. For each score we need to go through the counts and add them all up.

```
scores.forEach(scoreObject  => {
  console.log('Looking at ' + scoreObject.name);
  score_map_keys.forEach(key => {    
    let count = score_map[key];   
    if (key >= scoreObject.low && key <= scoreObject.high) {
      console.log(key + ' matches the allowed range');
      scoreObject.count = scoreObject.count+count
    }
  });
})

console.log(scores);
```

You can find working code in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j6734vtq/24/

Open up the console (ctr+shift+i) and press run.

Comment: Bergur, Thank you so much for explaining the proccess and providing a great answer that can be easily understood. You are Awesome.